# In C++, is it possible to "overload" an object which is a member of another class?

Tags: c++, class, object, overloading

I have a class `driver` which does a bunch of computations based on a member, which is an object of another class `computation_A`. The header for `driver` looks like:

```
// driver.hpp

#ifndef DRIVER
#define DRIVER

class driver
{
   public:

   // Making this public may be considered bad practice but this is for illustration purposes only:
   computation_A compute;

   void do_computation_1();
   void do_computation_2();
};

#endif
```

The source looks like:

```
// driver.cpp

void driver::do_computation_1()
{
    compute.do_something;

    // use the results somehow
}

void driver::do_computation_2()
{
    compute.do_another_thing;

    // use the results somehow
}
```

In reality, the source is large and contains many calls to members of `compute`.

Now, I want `driver` to be able to support another kind of computational class, `computation_B`, based on some run-time criterion, e.g. a boolean switch `bool use_B`.
`computation_B` will have all the same function names as `computation_A`, but different functionality (e.g. maybe `computation_A` and `computation_B` both derive from an abstract class `computation` - I have some flexibility here).

Furthermore, all subsequent function calls in `driver.cpp` will be identical. For example, if `use_B` is set to `true` (maybe in an `Initialize` method), then `compute.do_something` in `driver::do_computation_1` will do the thing defined in `computation_B`. In other words, **nothing actually changes in `driver.cpp`, it just calls all the same functions but of a different class**.

I suppose I'm looking for a way to overload `compute`.

Is there a way for me to achieve this **without making significant changes to `driver.cpp`**? I don't mind making changes to `driver.hpp`, but intuitively I feel that I shouldn't have to rewrite all the same functions in `driver.cpp`.

As a solution, the first thing that comes to mind is to use templates somehow. But I can't figure out how. My understanding is that templates kick in at compile time, but the value of `use_B` isn't known until run time (e.g. it is a user input).

Another option is to declare `compute` as a pointer to an abstract class `computation`. Then, later on, point `compute` to the members `compute_A` or `compute_B` of classes `computation_A` or `computation_B`, respectively, depending on `use_B`. This would require me to change all function calls `compute.do...` to `compute->do...`. This is pretty easy to do I guess, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution (I'm not a very experienced coder, and I have found that there's always a better way than what I think is a good way...)

Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly the type of situation that polymorphism is meant for. And you already mentioned the solution - "*maybe `computation_A` and `computation_B` both derive from an abstract class `computation`*". Make `compute` be a `computation*` pointer that points at a `computation_A` or `computation_B` object as needed.

Comment: This is exactly what polymorphism was invented for. In fact, when I read your post I thought you were setting the question up for a self-answer (which would be OK).  You'll need to make `compute` a pointer or reference though for it to work.

Comment: My reason for asking the question despite seeming to have an answer (besides wondering if there's a better answer) is that a colleague with more experience than me repeatedly has told me "if you're using C++, never use pointers" which often confuses me. Thanks for the comments though, I'm more confident about this solution now.

Comment: Alas, programmers with long experience do not always know what they're talking about.

Comment: "never use pointers" should be "avoid using owning raw pointers".  `std::unique_ptr<computation>` (or `std::shared_ptr<computation>` if you _really_ need shared ownership) is the answer to that.

Comment: @EM_IE Does ```computation_a``` contain any data members you want to keep directly within ```driver```? I am asking because ```unique_ptr<computation>``` (plus reference to contents of unique_ptr if you want to avoid switching from ```.``` to ```->```) is great solution as long as there were no (e.g. performance) reasons originally that caused ```computation_a``` to be stored directly within ```driver```.

Comment: @Slimak Data of `computation` does need to be accessed directly within `driver`. I could accomplish this by making the objects `compute_A` and `compute_B` members of `driver`, and the pointer `compute` can point to one of them depending on the need. This clutters the header a bit, but it's okay - they're not big memory-wise. In terms of performance, the expensive operations take place inside `computation`, e.g. in `compute.do_something`. Therefore, I think the dereferencing should have negligible cost, unless I'm misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: @EM_IE dereferencig is cheap, what can be more costly is accessing 2 distinctive memory regions. In your current model you might have ```[0x1000 driver [ 0x1004 compute_a ] ]```. With unique ptr you will have ```[0x1000 driver [0x1004 uniqe_ptr->0x8000]]; [0x8000 compute_x]``` (0x are example addresses). I would assume that if there were no comments about the reasons of putting ```compute_a``` in driver, then there were no such specific reasons :). Anyway if you really need to keep compute_X inside driver physically, there are old good unions at your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different approaches. Below few of them aiming at low number of
changes in `driver.cpp` file. Note that form is very terse and skeleton.

Case 1 --- You know types at compile time. Simple template based solution.

```
    struct mult
    {
        int a; 
        double do_work(int b) { return a * b; }
    };
    struct add
    {   
        double a;
        double do_work(int b) { return a + b;}
    };
    template <class C> struct driver
    {
        C c;
        int x; 
        void foo() { std::cout << c.a << "|" << c.do_work(x) << "\n"; }
    };

// ...

    driver<add> a(1);
    driver<mult> m(1.0);
    a.x = 10;
    m.x = 20;
    a.foo();
    m.foo();
```

Case 2 --- you know types only at runtime --- virtual functions look like best solution

```
struct base
{
    virtual double& a() = 0;
    virtual double do_work(int b) = 0;
    virtual ~base() {};
};
class mult : public base
{
    double a_; // note that keeping int here would make impl of a() complicated
public:
    mult(double d) : a_(d) {};
    double& a() override { return a_; }
    double do_work(int b) override { return a() * b; }
};
class add : public base
{
    double a_;
public:
    add(int i) : a_(i) {};
    double& a() override { return a_; }
    double do_work(int b) override { return a() + b;}
};

// ...

    driver a(1), m(1.0);
    a.x = 10;
    m.x = 20;
    a.foo();
    m.foo();
```

Subcase A --- you don't have strong need to keep add/mult inside driver (99% of cases)

```
    struct driver
    {
        driver(int i) : c(std::make_unique<add>(i)) {}
        driver(double d) : c(std::make_unique<mult>(d)) {}
        // if copyability is needed then depending on circumstances
        // add copy constructor or replace uniqe_ptr with shared_ptr

        std::unique_ptr<base> c;
        int x;
        void foo() { std::cout << c->a() << "|" << c->do_work(x) << "\n"; }
    };

    std::vector<driver> v;
```

Subcase B --- you have strong reasons to keep add/mult directly within driver
(such strong reason can be e.g. measured unacceptable degradation in performance)

```
    union amu // this exposes a and m, you may want encapsulate amu in class
    {
        add a;
        mult m;
        amu(int i) : a(i) {};
        amu(double d) : m(d) {};
        base& operator*() {return *static_cast<base*>(&a);}
        base* operator->() {return static_cast<base*>(&a);}
        ~amu() {static_cast<base*>(&a)->~base();};
    };

    struct driver
    {
        driver(int i) : c(i) {}
        driver(double d) : c(d) {}
        amu c;
        int x;
        void foo() { std::cout << c->a() << "|" << c->do_work(x) << "\n"; }
    }
```